# How to get the localized keyboard-key-name in VS C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` that has the `ShortcutKeys` Ctrl+Oemcomma (i.e. `Ctrl+,`). I want to show that shortcut near the item-name, so the user can see that shortcut. Unluckily it's shown as `Ctrl+Oemcomma` and not as the more understandable `Ctrl+,`.

There's the property ShortcutKeyDisplayString that overrides the automatic created string, so that way one can fix it. But as soon as the application is run in a language that doesn't call the control-key `Ctrl` (e.g. in germany it's called `Strg`), that ShortcutKeyDisplayString looks wrong, as all other automatic created shortcut-descriptions are translated (i.e. if in an english OS a description is displayed as `Ctrl+S`, in a german OS it then displays `Strg+S`).

Is there a function that returns the localized name of a key so that I could use that to set the ShortcutKeyDisplayString? I.e. I'm looking for a function that returns `Ctrl` in an english OS and `Strg` in a german OS etc. I tried `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control.ToString()`, but that of course just returns `Control`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a `TypeConverter` for `Keys` enum type.
We inherit from `KeysConverter` as this is the associated `TypeConverter` of `Keys` and we need to handle only the `Keys.Oemcomma` value.

```
public class ShortcutKeysConverter : KeysConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (Type.Equals(destinationType, typeof(string)) && value is Keys)
        {
            var key = (Keys)value;

            if (key.HasFlag(Keys.Oemcomma))
            {
                string defaultDisplayString =
                    base
                        .ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
                        .ToString();

                return defaultDisplayString.Replace(Keys.Oemcomma.ToString(), ",");
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Then in your `Program.cs` before callign `Application.Run(...)`:

```
TypeDescriptor
    .AddAttributes(
        typeof(Keys),
        new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ShortcutKeysConverter))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gabors answer I solved it as follows. It might be hacky but it's short and works.

```
settingsToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = ((new KeysConverter()).ConvertTo(Keys.Control, typeof(string))).ToString().Replace("None", ",");
```