# Keyboard keys localization

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I am working on menu for shortcut settings of my application. Application does support two languages (English and German), so I need to be able to show culture depended string. E.g. Ctrl+Ins for "en-US" and Strg+Einfg for "de-DE".

Considering that amount of possible keys is not very big i could define resources for each key, but i assume that this problem isn't uncommon and there should be built-in functionality or well know library for this purpose.

I have tried ConvertToString() from System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter :

```
var kc = new System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter();
var de = kc.ConvertToString(null, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), Keys.Insert);
Console.WriteLine(de);
```

And GetDisplayStringForCulture() from System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture :

```
System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture kg = new KeyGesture(Key.Insert);
var de = kg.GetDisplayStringForCulture(new CultureInfo("de-AT"));
Console.WriteLine(de);
```

But both of them return english "Ins" and "Insert" respectively.

So basically I am looking for method that will accept some kind of standard key class and culture and return respective localized string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100079/how-to-get-the-localized-keyboard-key-name-in-vs-c-sharp?

Comment: @CodeCaster  
`var x = kc.ConvertTo(null, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), Keys.Insert, typeof (String));`  
`Console.WriteLine(x);`  
Will return "Ins".  
So basically works same way as as ConvertToString() from exemple of mine.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension . Besides binding to DependencyProperties in Xaml (WPF stuff), you can retrieve localized resource values programmatically in code, too.

Comment: @Yeah69  My question is not about working with resources rather a way to populate them if there is no way manage without them.

Comment: @Yeah69 My pardon. My previous comment is a bit misleading. What I wanted to say is that keys name do not have variety inside of one language so the idea that every programmer will define his own string resources for application of his is quite uncomfortable. So maybe there is a way to obtain some source that could be just included in solution to provide developer with necessary localized keys names.

Answer (score -1):

I have no time to test it on my own, but you could try my approach below

Referring to these two posts

(US English)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

(German) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Strg+Einfg is equivalent with

```
'VB
If E.KeyCode = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Insert) Then...

//C#
if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Control | Keys.Insert)) {...
```

To show the current input language, you could try

```
MsgBox(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName)
```